# Android Data binding debugging

Tags: android, gradle, data-binding

I'm starting with android's databinding tools but every time i come to run the program i get a build error that my.package.databinding does not exist.
that is the only error i get:

```
 Error:(15, 47) error: package a.b.c.d.databinding does not exist
```

the i try to review all the bindings and i finally find the problem. but this process is too slow and will get slower as i use more bindings.

is there any way that the build process or gradle tells me exactly what is the probelm with my code and why they could'nt create the binding classes.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best place to report this is b.android.com.

We've received some reports that when there is a java code mistake, sometimes, it does not build binding files which is wrong but we are struggling to reproduce it.

So if you can create a bug report w/ a project to reproduce, we'll try to fix it asap.

Comment: I'm suffering from this problem now. It all started with me copy/pasting existing viewmodel class , as well as XML layout.. then forgetting to update the reference to the viewmodel in the XML. I fixed it and still, it won't find the databinding any more.